# mystic 0.3.3 has requirement numpy<1.16.0,>=1.0, but you'll have numpy 1.16.2 which is incompatible

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using python 3.7 on my windows 10 system.I'm trying to install library reuqests. So I used following code

```
pip install requests
```

I got the error message

```
mystic 0.3.3 has requirement numpy<1.16.0,>=1.0, but you'll have numpy 1.16.2 which is incompatible.
```

Can you suggest me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue during fastai package installation, uninstalled numpy and installing mystic package using anaconda prompt fixed the issue

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install mystic
```